# See IIS website from another machine in same network

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I have Website in my localhost (IIS) on Windows 8.1, I can access it from:

- http://localhost/

It binded to **"All Unassigned"** and Port **80** and **Localhost**.

But I can't access this website from another PC (windows 7) in same network.

Please notice that:

- Both are connected to same wireless modem
- I have **Eset SmartSecurity** on both of PCes and firewall are disabled.
- I can ping both in cmd like: 192.168.1.50
- In Windows 7 PC port 0.0.0.0:80 is bonded (I check it with **netstat -na** and result is: *TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING*)
- In Windows 7 PC Telnet 192.168.1.50 80 connected correctly
- In Windows 7 Pc also I installed IIS 7
- [image: Security Permission of website folder]

I'm really confused and don't know what to do!!!

Comment: im not sure, but i think you need to set read permissions to your website's folder for network user. i dont remember the exact name of the network user though.

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: go to inetpub/wwwroot on your c drive, find your website's folder there, right click -> properties -> security -> advanced -> change permissions -> add

Comment: When you say "can't access", what is the error message or result you are seeing in the browser? One place to check is in the F12/developer tools in your browser. Take a look at the Network panel to see what the web server is returning, or if the connection is even being established.

Comment: @ImranShams i think you are looking for the user **NETWORK SERVICE**, and dont forget to tick the "replace all child permissions...." box as well. set full read/write permissions to your website for the network user, and it should work

Comment: I add a image for more info, every thing is ok?

Comment: I try 192.168.1.50 and response is 404 not found

Comment: Are you trying to access the website by machine name (e.g. mymachine) or by IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.1)?

Comment: Both of them, But usually 192.168.1.50, Another IP is 192.168.1.52

Comment: Is the Windows firewall disabled on the host (windows 8) machine?

Comment: @JeffSiver Yes, I have ping in both of them, Some time timeout happens by with retry it will be OK

Comment: Ping working doesn't mean the windows firewall is disabled. And IIS is not allowed through the firewall by default (which is why I asked).

Comment: @JeffSiver I disabled firewall on both of them by right clicking on smart security 8, is there any other action to do?

Comment: I don't know, I'm unfamiliar with Eset Security. I would verify the Windows firewall is disabled on the Windows 8 machine (Windows Firewall in Control Panel). You might also want to disable the entire product suite on the Windows 7 machine in case it is blocking the website.

Comment: is  iis pointing to c:\inetpub\wwwroot ?

Comment: @ImranShams add read&write permissions to **NETWORK SERVICE**, that what lets other computers to access your website. **IIS_IUSR** is not enough.

Comment: @Banana Please show me how to do this?

Comment: @ImranShams in the box on that picture that you posted, click "change permissions", then click "add", then type "network service" and click "check name", once it becomes bold and has a underline, click ok. then back in that box with all permissions, click "change child permissions blablabla..." and click ok.  **NOTE: permission for the network service needs to be added on the SERVER pc.**

Comment: @Banana I do it but not working